# Speaking URL, Exclude from speaking URL does not funktion

Tags: typo3-7.6.x, realurl

(Tested with TYPO3 7.6 and RealURL 2.0.14 and 2.1.5)
My Tree:

```
+- [201] "General elements" (folder)
   +- [202] "Page 1"
      +- [203] "Page 2"
         +- [204] "Page 3"
```

I have tried to exclude the folder General elements in this URL
.../General elements/page1/page2/page3/
In the backend I have Enabled Page/General/Exclude from speaking URL and emptied the URL Cache and BE cache and everything but the folder won't disappear.
my realurl_conf.php is this:

```
            'fixedPostVars' => array(
            'ReturnDetail' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[annonceType]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                        'projekte' => 0,
                        'stellen' => 1,
                        'intern' => 2
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass',
                ),
            ),
            '148' => 'ReturnDetail',
            '202' => 'ReturnDetail',
 'newsDetailConfiguration' => array(
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[action]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[controller]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[returnAction]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[returnId]',
                    'valueMap' => array(
                    ),
                    'noMatch' => 'bypass'
                ),
                array(
                    'GETvar' => 'tx_topitannoncen_annoncenlisting[annonce]',
                    'lookUpTable' =>
                        array(
                            'table' => 'tx_topitannoncen_domain_model_annonce',
                            'id_field' => 'uid',
                            'alias_field' => "concat(advert_title,'-',advert_number)",
                            'addWhereClause' => ' AND NOT deleted',
                            'useUniqueCache' => 1,
                            'useUniqueCache_conf' =>
                                array(
                                    'strtolower' => 1,
                                    'spaceCharacter' => '_',
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
            ),
            '173' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
            '204' => 'newsDetailConfiguration',
```

148 and 202 are the Folders which should be hide in the url

but what I get is

```
http://www.~/General-elements/Page1/Page2/Page3/engin-mw-667-9178/
```

I want it like this

```
http://www.~/Page1/Page2/detail/engin-mw-667-9178/
```

Comment: could you please enhance your page tree display with the uids of those pages (like `options.pageTree.showPageIdWithTitle = 1` in the user-TSconfig):  like: `- [123] "General Elements"`

Comment: the page Tree is like this:  - General elements [201]  -page 1 [202] -Page 2 [203]- Page 3 [204] . I have two domains, in the First one the Folder is hide successfully but not in the second one  !

Comment: can you also give examplas of the URL you get and what URL you expect to get? (you should be able to edit your question to provide additional information in a formatted way)

Comment: I think the Problem is somewhere else. The href from realURL is putting together  dynamically by an extention and the BE has no effect here.